# Taking out fruits seeds/pits

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What word normally would you use for **taking out the seeds of  watermelon/melon/orange" or e.g. mango pit?
Is it just "to take out" or you would usually use the same words? (I meen "to seed a melon" or "to pit a mango".)

Comment: Worth noting that one would normally remove the seeds from a cataloupe melon, or similar because the seeds are all in the centre. But in watermelon, the seeds are embedded in the edible flesh, so watermelon is normally served sliced, with seeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, but "taking out the seeds" or "removing the seeds" is perfectly natural and can be employed with any seed-containing fruit or veg. Another possibility is:

> to deseed - e.g. 'deseed the tomatoes before adding them to the stew'

There are sometimes specific verbs used depending on the type of fruit or vegetable. The seeds of an apple, for example, are contained within a core. You can say `'to core an apple'`, meaning to remove the entire core including the seeds. Or if there is a stone (cherry, avocado, plum, etc), you can use the verb `'to destone'`.  This is also called a 'pit' and the verb `'to pit'` means to remove the pit (e.g. to pit a cherry)

But you can always use the catch-all phrase `"to remove the [ X ] "` where X might be seeds, a core, a stone, stem, pith, etc.

Comment: Thank you @kandyman; you pit a peach, core an apple; but how about i.e. a cantaloupe?

Comment: I think "deseed" is most appropriate for a cantaloupe. Or again, "remove the seeds".

Answer (score 2):

Using *to pit* is fine:

> : to remove the pit from (a fruit)

(entry 4 of 5 in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pit))

Here are some example sentences from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pit#pit_Noun_230):

> Remove the pit from (fruit).
>
> - ‘I cut the cherries in half and pitted them.’
> - ‘Wash fruits well, pit and peal peaches and core pears.’
> - ‘Just before serving, peel and pit the avocado.’
> - ‘Leave some cherries whole so people can see later on how hard you worked pitting real cherries.’
> - ‘If you're pitting cherries, do it inside a Ziploc bag.’

Comment: Thank you @glorfindel; but how about watermelons or melons?